# Is using transaction with each NHibernate operation necessary in order to using caching?

Tags: nhibernate, transactions

Is using transaction with each NHibernate operation necessary in order to using caching and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not use an explicit transaction. Most databases will use implicit transactions. This means that each query you make will be wrapped in a transaction that is committed upon query completion. See this article: [**Use Of Implicit Transactions Is Discouraged**](http://nhprof.com/Learn/Alerts/DoNotUseImplicitTransactions)

So it is a good idea to wrap your application actions in transactions, even if all they do is fetch data. Especially since your question is dealing with caching, you want to use transactions if you want to make use of the 2nd level cache as per the article referenced.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But I was missing something in my question. So updated my question.

Comment: @afsharm, if the thing that was missing was caching, see my answer again.

Comment: In a nutshell: NH won't use 2nd level cache if you don't use a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

In database systems, transactions are intended to wrap several smaller atomic operations into one larger operation.

The canonical example is that of moving money from one checking account to another.  The two atomic operations are:

1. Debit $x.xx from one account
2. Credit $x.xx to another account

These two atomic operations are wrapped in a transaction so that, if one of the operations fails, you can roll back the entire transaction, and the system won't be left in a state where the bank or the customer is left with too much or too little money, or there is money unaccounted for.

So if your operation is a simple atomic one, like changing a single field in a table, then no, I do not believe you need a transaction for that.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But I was missing something in my question. So updated my question.

Comment: @Robert Harvey

I really get an Idea from you answer.

I now face with the problem with many atomic operations for example

GetMember

ResetPassword

SendEmail

each operation has it own Transaction so I need to get result for each operation 

It would be nice if I could wrap all operation in single transaction and it will rollback if any operation fail.

for now I need to manual detect error like this 

var result = GetMember();
if(result)
result = ResetPassword();
if(result)
result = SendEmail();

so many if check Therefore do you have any example design pattern for ASP.NET WebForm. Thanks

Comment: @embarus: What you are describing is program logic, not database operations (although the database might be involved).  If you want to wrap these operations in a database transaction, you have to express them in SQL.